# Determine $n$ so that the difference between the $n$-th Taylor-polynomial of $\sin(x)$ with $x_0=0$ and $\sin(x)$ on $[-3,3]$ is at most $10^{-6}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

$\sin(x)$ can be expressed as a power series: $$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

How can I determine how large $n$ has to be, so that the difference between the $n$-th Taylor-polynomial of $\sin(x)$  with $x_0=0$ and $\sin(x)$ on $[-3,3]$ is at most $10^{-6}$?

I should use the **Lagrange-remainder** to answer this question:
$$R_n(x,x_0)=\frac{f^{n+1}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series would diverge at the egde of the interval $[-3,3]$, so the remainder at the endpoints should be less than $10^{-6}$. $|f^{(n+1)}(\xi)|$ < 1, hence we have $$|R_n| \le \frac{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$ Next since we have two unknowns we need to do trial and error.

```
| n |  upper bound |
| 1 |      4.5     |
| 2 |      4.5     |
| 3 |      3.8     |
| 7 |       .43    | 
|10 |       .016   |
|15 |      1.1e-5  |
|16 |      2.0e-6  | 
|17 |      3.3e-7  |
```

So 17 I guess. 
Following are the values I computed using a python program.

```
0  ==>  2.85887999194
1  ==>  1.64112000806
2  ==>  0.38387999194
3  ==>  0.0500485794884
4  ==>  0.00419249194013
5  ==>  0.000245413904023
6  ==>  1.06191254474e-05
7  ==>  3.53718672796e-07
8  ==>  9.35337529651e-09
```

We get error less than $1e-6$ after the 7th term in the series. Which means we need to take terms till $x^{15}$.

Comment: Can you explain what you did a bit more? I just started learning about taylor series yesterday so it's difficult for me. I think in the table beginning from $n=7$ your $n's$ are always $1$ too big. But what I actually wanted to know is what you did before. What's the thinking process behind it? Why does the series diverge at the end of the interval and why is $|f^{(n+1)(\xi)}|<1$ and how does that result in that formula or where does it come from? Thanks! (As I said, just heard about it yesterday so I dont grasp it yet)

Comment: Series diverges at the end of the interval because at that point $(x-x_a)^n$ has the largest value. I say $|f^{(n+1)(\xi)}|<1$ because the function is a $\sin$ which has the maximum value of $1$. If you can find some upper bound,$Q$, $f^{n+1}\le Q$ then you can write that, $|R_n| \le Q\frac{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$. See the wikipedia page of taylor series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem